# Kendo mvc grid : Dropdown open and immediately close at first click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

am using Batch Editing Kendo MVC Grid and I have Editor Column Display DropDownList when click dropdown it open and closes immediately . I Works Perfect at Microsoft Edge & FireFox But Not at Chrome

that happened when click add new record , then need to open drop down inside grid

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<HMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.Inventory.ServiceInvoiceViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.SupplierService).ClientTemplate("#=SupplierService.NameEn#").Width(300);

    columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity).Width(150);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Amouunt).Width(150).ClientFooterTemplate("Total Amount: #=sum#");
    columns.Bound(p => p.CostCenter).ClientTemplate("#=CostCenter.NameEn#").Width(300);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Remarks).Width(150);
    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(120);
})
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
{
    toolBar.Create().Text(HMS.Resources.Inventory.SupplierService.addnewService);
    //toolBar.Save();
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
     .Aggregates(aggregates =>
     {

         aggregates.Add(p => p.Amouunt).Sum();
     })
   .Batch(true)
  .ServerOperation(false)
 .Model(model =>
  {
model.Id(p => p.Id);
model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
model.Field(p => p.SupplierService).DefaultValue(
    ViewData["defaultService"] as HMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.Inventory.SupplierServiceViewModel);
model.Field(p => p.CostCenter).DefaultValue(
   ViewData["defaultCostCenter"] as HMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.CostCenterViewModel);
 })
    .PageSize(20)
    //.Read(read => read.Action("EditingCustom_Read", "Grid"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("EditingCustom_Create", "SupplierInvoice"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingCustom_Update", "SupplierInvoice"))
//.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingCustom_Destroy", "Grid"))
)
)



 @model HMS.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.CostCenterViewModel
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;" })
    .DataValueField("CostCenterId")
    .DataTextField("NameEn")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["CostCenters"]))
```